# C++: Crashes when 2D array element is referenced while overloading ostream >>

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, allocation

I'm attempting to create a Matrix class that contains a 2D array using dynamically allocated memory.

```
class Matrix{
  int sized;
  Complex **matrix = NULL;
public:
  Matrix(int);
  Matrix(int, vector<Complex>);
  Matrix();
  bool checkDom(Matrix, Matrix);
  int size();
  void size(unsigned int);
```

Here is my constructor for the Matrix, which copies values of type Complex into each element.

```
Matrix::Matrix(int sizer, vector<Complex> inputList) {

  sized = sizer;

  //Init all to 0+0i
  Complex** matrix = new Complex*[sizer];
  for (int i = 0; i < sizer; ++i)
      matrix[i] = new Complex[sizer];

  int count = 0;

  //Copy vector values into matrix
  for (int i = 0; i < sized; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sized; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = inputList[count];
        count++;
    }
}
```

}

If I insert a cout statement within this constructor, the matrices elements will print correctly:

```
//inside of constructor, prints all elements without a problem
for (int i = 0; i < sized; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sized; j++) {
            os << right << setw(6) << matrix[i][j];
        }
            os << endl;
    }
```

However, while operator overloading the >> operator to print the matrix, it crashes (no error at compile time).

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Matrix &matprint){
    for (int i = 0; i < matprint.sized; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matprint.sized; j++) {
            os << right << setw(6) << matprint.matrix[i][j];
        }
            os << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

It seems to happen whenever I want to send a matrix element to the output stream using dot notation. I get the error

Unhandled exception at 0x000E8943 in ConsoleApplication7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

My debugger also lists the matprint.matrix value as 0x00000000. I'm having trouble figuring out exactly where my reference goes wrong! Thanks!

This is where the operator is invoked, in main:

```
Matrix  mat2(2, mat_vals);
cout << mat2;
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger already, to track the problem down?

Comment: Show us the code where you invoke the operator.

Comment: I see little reason to use raw C-style arrays when you're using `std::vector`, especially with `new[]`.

Comment: I'm learning how to use dynamically allocated arrays so it is a requirement.

Comment: @Kevin Also, shouldn't be `ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, /*>>*/ const /*<<*/ Matrix &matprint)` be sufficient for read only access?

Comment: Yes, however I believe it is not relevant to my issue. I think I am passing the matrix incorrectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
Complex** matrix = new Complex*[sizer];
```

is declaring a new object named `matrix` that is local to the scope of the constructor. Its name *hides* the data member of the same name. So when you derference it inside the operator function, you'll be derferencing the data member whose value hasn't changed from `NULL`, hence the crash.

Take away the type and then it becomes an assignment:

```
matrix = new Complex*[sizer];
```